# django-rest-framerwork serializer how to get user id

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

a model like this:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    num_stars = models.IntegerField()
```

and serializer:

```
class AlbumSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    count=serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        module=Album
        fields=('__all__')
```

I just want know how can I get user.id in serializer

Answer (score 2):

Django REST framework's serializers uses a context to keep those things. It is used to find out the associated hostname when using HyperlinkedSerializers and is documentated [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context)

By default, generic view do add the current request, which means that you are able to do:

```
class AlbumSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    count=serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        module=Album
        fields=('__all__')

    def get_count(self,obj):
        # Provided the user is logged:
        user_id = self.context['request'].user.id
        # Now do whatever with user_id
        return
```

Answer (score 1):

Serializer:

```
class AlbumSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    count=serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        module=Album
        fields=('__all__')

    def get_count(self,obj):
        request = self.context.get("request")
        user_id = request.user.id

        return
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note here is that you must not access request other than the `views`. If you want to access the *request* then you must pass the *context* explicilty because django rest framework implicitly do not pass the *request* to serializer.

```
class MyAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
    query_set = MyObjects.objects.all()

    serializer = MySerializer(query_set,
                              context={'request': request},
                              many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

**Note:** This is case when you are using `APIView` or any other base class view. But in case of `ViewSets` where you don't have to override methods Django Rest Framework will automatically send the `request` to `Serializer` class. I hope it clears the concept !

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass  "context={'request': request}" along with queryset in serializer from view, then you can get user in serailizer by self.context['request'].user.id.
**Note**: this will work if your view is token authenticated .

Comment: when calling `self.get_serializer()` in a view, context is passed automatically